# Copy customizer options to child theme

Tags: database, child-theme, theme-customizer

I am using the OceanWP theme and customized it with the WordPress Customizer feature. Then, I created a child theme based on OceanWP, because I introducted some new shortcodes and did not want to alter the base theme. Unfortunately, when I switch themes, all my customization is lost.

I know that the customization is stored in the WordPress options table. I found `theme_mods_ocean` and copied the content to `theme_mods_myChildTheme`. I can store the changes, but as soon as I reload the blog, the database entry is reverted to its initial value.

How is this possible? Is there any other place where the customization is saved and restored from? I do not want to re-configure the entire child theme, if possible.

Comment: WordPress doesn't store theme mods anywhere else, but can't be sure that your parent theme doesn't. Does `myChildTheme`, where you've copied the database row, match the folder name of your child theme exactly?

Comment: Yes, it does. WordPress created that entry anyway, so the name should be correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserving theme settings in child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163440/preserving-theme-settings-in-child-theme)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely backup your database FIRST before trying this out.

I just tested changing the `option_name` of a set of customizer changes to match a different theme, and it appears we can make the customizer changes switch to another theme simply by changing the option_name to match our new theme, instead of copying the option_value serialized data over. I didn't have a child theme handy to test this, but the premise is the same.

First, using your favourite DB editor find the option for `theme_mods_myChildTheme` in your options table, and change the option_name to something like theme_mods_myChildTheme-backup, then you can easily switch back to this if you need to.

Next find the option for `theme_mods_ocean`, and edit the option_name to be `theme_mods_myChildTheme`.

Finally go visit the Appearance >> Customize page in your child theme, and you should see all the customizer option values from your parent theme are set there now. Keep in mind this means these values are no longer set for your other theme.

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: This approach worked for me. I simply went to `wp_options` table, found the record with the field `option_name` set to *theme_mods_parent*, copied the text found in `option_value` to the record with the field `option_name` set to *theme_mods_child*. Of course you have to replace *parent* and *child* with the actual names of your themes.

Comment: There's a better option over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/277994

Answer (score 1):

I was able to export and import the Customizer settings using this Plugin :
Customizer Export/Import (Version 0.9.1 | By The Beaver Builder Team).
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/

It works like a charm and is safer than the database manipulation method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the weak point of Customizer vs Child Themes. All Customizers options are stored in the db and they are meant to be used with the original theme. If you switch to another theme (i.e. your child theme), the options remain bound to the original one.

As an option, you should deeply study the content of your options table theme_mods for the original theme, an try to "translate" them into your child style.css (whenever possible.)